# Best way to check if a text file containing 1 billion rows of number from 1 to 1B

Tags: algorithm

If I had a program to generate 1 billion numbers and output it to a text file. What is the best way to check if that file containing enough number?
For example my output text file should be like below

```
1
2
....
1001
1002
1003
...
1000000000
```

The **auditor program** should check if the file contains 1 billion rows and those number must be in ascending order

Comment: What do you mean by **enough number**?

Comment: What makes you think your program that writes a billion numbers might not write a billion numbers?

Comment: that why I need another program to audit my generator :D

Comment: @Phillip meaning that it containing enough 1 billion number and the number should be in ascending order

Comment: But you do realize writing a program that _correctly_ writes a sequence of numbers is far easier than writing a program which verifies that a file contains a _correct_ sequence of numbers, and in addition the sequence is ordered, don't you?

Comment: Could you elaborate, what is **enough 1 billion number**? Does it differ somehow from just **1 billion numbers**?

Comment: If so, you can just input the numbers from that file and check if they are 1 billion and in order. It will take only O(n)

Comment: @CiaPan totally agreed that writing a program that verify a file containing 1 billion rows of number from 1 to 1000000 is a more difficult task. But anyway, I need some advise :D

Comment: Your sample file ends at a million rather than a billion?

Comment: Here is an outline of a possible solution: 1) read a line of text, verify if it's not empty and contains a proper number and only one number; if any condition fails, exit with an error message; otherwise store the number; 2) repeat 1 bn. times minus 1: read a line of text, verify if it's not empty and contains a proper number and only one number and the number is greater than the stored one by 1; if any condition fails, exit with an error message; otherwise replace the stored number with a newly readed one; [to be continued]

Comment: [continued] 3) after 1 bn. number got read and verified, check if the file contains any unread data; if so, exit with an error message, otherwise exit with a success message.

Comment: As @MarkSetchell points out, your example suggests your data consist of 1 million rows, not 1 billion.

Comment: As a quick check at the start, rather than reading the entire file, you could check the file size and ensure it is at least 9888888899 bytes which is the minimum for the numbers 1..1000,000,000 and potentially quickly discount truncated/incomplete files without reading them all the way through.

Comment: @MarkSetchell my bad, I had updated the sample

Comment: @MarkSetchell You're right - provided the input is a random-access file, whose size can be checked quite easily. In a case of a sequential file, however, (e.g. piped-in as a standard input stream) there is no shortcut.

Answer (score 2):

The normal approach would be just to read through the file and check this. The following pseudo-code<sup>(1)</sup> would be one approach:

```
set expected to zero
for each line in file:
    add one to expected
    if line not equal to expected:
        exit with failure indication
if expected is not one billion:
    exit with failure indication
exit with success indication
```

This allows you to indicate failure immediately that a bad line is found, the only case where you have to process the entire file is if it's valid.

That algorithm is, of course, if your numbers need to be consecutive as well as ascending, which appears to be the case.

There are potential optimisations that could be used to pre-check things (such as the file being of a minimum size that will allow it to contain all the numbers). But, until you've got the functionality done correctly, I'd be holding off doing those.

---

<sup>(1)</sup> Keep in mind that there are real-world issues you'll need to contend with when implementing in a real language. This includes things such as opening the file, reading each line into a variable, and converting between strings and integers.

I haven't covered that in detail since this question is tagged `algorithm`.

Comment: You already have my vote, but as it stands, your program would fail to detect a file with either too few or too many lines.

Comment: Good point, @MarkSetchell, can't believe I missed that. I think I've fixed it now.